# Where should I place bestseller? method - in model or somewhere else?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, coding-style

I've got some simple model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categories
end
```

Now I would like to check in some service, if product is a bestseller and do other action for it:

```
class ProductService
  def remind
    Product.all.each do |product|
      puts product unless bestseller?
    end
  end
end
```

So now what is the best place to put the `bestseller?` method - inside model or in the service as private method?
In future it may be used in some other services or actions. 
Do you think the model is right place to put this method there?
Example of bestsellers method (bestsellers are picked manualy by adding to category 'bestsellers':

```
def bestseller?(product)
  product.categories.include?(BESTSELLER_CATEGORY_ID)
end
```

or

```
def bestseller?(product_id)
  Category.find(BESTSELLER_CATEGORY_ID).products.include?(product_id)
end
```

I still haven't decided which one is better (both do the same)

Comment: How you are saying that the product is `bestseller`? Is `bestseller` a field or method? Please post the relevant code.

Comment: @Pavan right, sorry for not adding relevant code. Updated :)